# VS-Code download the same file every time I start it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I don't know why, but every single time I open VS-Code, the same files starts downloading, even if I just restarted it.
for example, in my case, the C# extension starts downloading Omnisharp every time I open VS-Code, even if it's already downloaded and installed.
is there any solution for that?